# SSIS ETL - Is it a good practice to have the destination DB pull data from sources directly

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have an ETL package that moves data from a number of source SQL Server DBs to a single destination SQL Server DB. All these DBs are on the same server. The destination DB contains a large number of views that reference the source DBs. E.g. `SELECT * FROM SourceDB1.dbo.Transactions`.

So the majority of the data goes directly `source DB => destination DB`, without passing through the SSIS server. I'm new to SSIS and wondering if this is a good thing to do, or should I look into changing the process.

Comment: I wouldn't have a problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I started learning about ETL and data migration using SSIS I was always told that it is best practice to first move the data into a staging database where you can validate the data, deduplicate, clean etc in there then move it to the destination DB

Answer (score 3):

Time passes, your company grows. You stand up Server2 and have SourceDBN on there. Now what? Your pattern of `SELECT * FROM SourceDB.dbo.Transactions` breaks.

SourceDB27, that client pays us a *lot* of money and so they ask us to add column `FooBitsWhatsIt` to their Transactions table. Now your `SELECT *` breaks because you have inconsistent columns across your ecosystem.

Someone writes a big query that takes a while to process - the people in the destination database are negatively impacting the ability of the Source databases to do their regular activity. Had the data been copied over to the destination and not merely referenced, there would be isolation between source and destination activities.

Generally speaking, the above costs and risks outweigh the additional development, storage and processing costs.